# How to use applymap for column wise multiplication across two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I just loaded in two excelsheets using pandas read_excel into 2 dataframes.

Is it possible to applymap on dataframe A's cells using dataframe B's cell data based on row and col index?

Below is an example:

Dataframe A

[image: Dataframe A]

Dataframe B

[image: Dataframe B]

assuming applymay uses a simple function of all of Dataframe A's row [i] multiply by Dataframe B's cell [i][0]

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use broadcasting, I don't think `df.applymap` is applicable here:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(A.values * B.values)
```

Demo:

```
In [987]: A
Out[987]: 
   Col1  Col2
0     1     2
1     2     3
2     3     4

In [988]: B
Out[988]: 
   Col1
0    10
1    20
2    30

In [989]: pd.DataFrame(A.values * B.values, columns=A.columns)
Out[989]: 
   Col1  Col2
0    10    20
1    40    60
2    90   120
```

---

You may consider using `df.apply`:

```
In [1004]: A.apply(lambda x: x * B.Col1.values, 0)
Out[1004]: 
   Col1  Col2
0    10    20
1    40    60
2    90   120
```

A [slight simplification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45814370/4909087) using `df.mul`:

```
In [1107]: A.mul(B.Col1, 0)
Out[1107]: 
   Col1  Col2
0    10    20
1    40    60
2    90   120
```

Comment: gosh, was overthinking the problem!

Comment: @KennethLiow Found an even simpler version: `A.mul(B.Col1, 0)`